# how to get a sub parent web element component between many div in selenium xpath?

Tags: java, html, xpath, automation, selenium-ide

I want to get the sub parent element `<div class="post"/>` given the text of a post in this case given the text "post2" that is the second div in the code
there are many posts in a page.

I tried to use an xpath like this that I did thinking that is possible find between in the sub-parents web elements:
"//div[@id='content']//span[contains(text(), 'post2')]/.//*[@class='post']"

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="right">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="post-content">
                    <span>
                        post1
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="right">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="post-content">
                    <span>
                        post2
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

exists any other solution for that or maybe the xpath is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

a solution that exists is using the "ancestor" keyword:

```
//div[@id='content']//span[contains(text(), 'post2')]/ancestor::div[@class='post']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can put the '`span` checking' as predicate for the `<div class="post">` :

```
//div[@id='content']/div[@class='post'][.//span[contains(text(),'post2')]]
```

This way you don't need to go back up the tree to the ancestor `<div class="post">` after going straight to the `span`