# Using xpath to Identifying a child by an input with a parent div in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, selenium-ide

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="_15u9 _6a _6b">
<div class="uiPopover _6a _6b">
<a class="_p _55pi _5vto _55_p _2agf _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft" href="#" style="max-width: 200px;" role="button">
<span></span>
</a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="audience_page" value="432218040132603" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
```

I have this in Selenium that can identify the input with the div:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//div/descendant::input[@name='audience_page']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

But I'd like to click on the link within the child div. I gave this a go:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//div/descendant::input[@name='audience_page']/div/a</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on this? I prefer to not use ids or css classes. Thanks.

[I looked at this post but I didn't think it quite answered the question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947216/how-to-get-a-sub-parent-web-element-component-between-many-div-in-selenium-xpath)

Comment: Where is your `a` tag closed?

Comment: Added, but the solution below works like a treat. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//div[input/@name='audience_page']/div/a
```

Basically, the XPath wil find the outer `div` by inspecting `name` attribute of the *child* element `input`. Then from such `div`, the XPath returns `/div/a` element.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks ;-) I'd never seen /@ used before - interesting!